# The area of the region bounded by $y=\text{arctanx}$ and its tangent line at the point $x=1$

Tags: calculus

The area of the region bounded by $y=\text{arctanx}$ and its tangent line at the point $x=1$

The problem is to find second intersection point.

[image: The graph of the tangent line and arctan(x)]

The tangent line is $y=\dfrac x 2+\dfrac \pi 4 - \dfrac12$

and the function $y=\text{arctanx}$

so solving together $y=\text{arctanx}=\dfrac x 2+\dfrac \pi 4 - \dfrac12$

But I am exhausted after trying to solve $$\text{arctanx}=\dfrac x 2+\dfrac \pi 4 - \dfrac12$$

I tried to open the general statement $tan(ax+b)$ but could not find usefull equations.

So, how to solve it?

Comment: There seems to be no closed form according to sage, but it's approximately $-3.0855738854768204$.

Comment: This has to be done numerically (using technology) If you enter...   $$\tan^{-1}(a) \sim \frac a2+\frac \pi 4 - \frac 12 \{a<0 \}$$  into Desmos, it will put the answer (about $-3.1$) into the variable $a$

Comment: without calculating the second point can we calculate the integral

Comment: I would consider $−3.0855738854768204$ a pretty good calculation of that point. It is not perfect, but then again, neither is our best known value of $\pi$ and nobody flinches at answers such as $\frac \pi 4$ and claims they aren't calculated. (Caveat - we do know $\pi$ to a *few* more decimal places than this point.) There is no *practical* use for the area that would not be wholly satisfied by this approximation.

Comment: @Daianne'deSouza Maybe give the solution of the second point any name and set up the integral. When you finish calculating then plug in the second point and use properties of it simplify the expression. The area is about $1.300089622155546170$